# Куда сохранить Upload файл в TomCat?

Tags: servlet, tomcat, upload

Есть необходимость сохранить image на сервер. Может есть простенькие библиотеки?
Пока остановился по туториалу оракла. Но вопрос в том куда сохранить файл на сервере и как создать путь?

В примере используется `String path = request.getParameter("MyPath");` но что я тут не указываю возвращает `null`
Есть еще такой вариант `path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");` который возвращает родительскую директорию проекта. Можно ли юзануть этот вариант на сервере?

```
@MultipartConfig
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final static Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(FileUploadServlet.class.getCanonicalName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7908187011456392847L;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        // Create path components to save the file
        final String path = request.getParameter("destination");
        final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStream filecontent = null;
        final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                    + fileName));
            filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

            int read;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File {0} being uploaded to {1}",
                    new Object[]{fileName, path});

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
            writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                    + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                    + "location.");
            writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}",
                    new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (filecontent != null) {
                filecontent.close();
            }
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFileName(final Part part) {
        final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
        for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return content.substring(
                        content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Servlet that uploads files to a user-defined destination";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> куда сохранить файл на сервере

Клиент не должен указывать путь к файлу, вместо этого путь к хранилищу файлов должен быть сконфигурирован в вашем приложении. Сделать это можно разными способами, например в параметрах инициализации самого сервлета:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- Параметр инициализации сервлета -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadFilesPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/srv/uploads</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

В сервлете значение параметра можно получить так:

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("uploadFilesPath");
```

> как создать путь?

```
File file = new File(...)
file.getParentFile().mkdirs()
```

Вызов getParentFile() осуществляется для того, чтобы не создавать папку с именем самого файла.

> Может есть простенькие библиотеки?

В них нет необходимости, стандартных средств языка Java вполне достаточно:

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
    String fileName = URLDecoder.decode(part.getSubmittedFileName(), "UTF-8");
    String path = getServletContext().getInitParameter("uploadFilesPath");
    File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName)
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
    java.nio.file.Files.copy(inputStream, file.toPath());
    inputStream.close();
}
```

В примере нет проверки на наличие файла с тем же именем, нет функций построения структуры папок (много файлов в одной папке может быть неудобно в поддержке), нет контроля безопасности - эти функции выходят за рамки вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("uploadFilesPath");
Мне кажется что бы это работало нужно устанавливать параметры в 
контекст сервлета, а не в конфиг
    <context-param>
        <param-name>uploadFilesPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/srv/uploads</param-value>
    </context-param>
```